# import csv in MySql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

Greetings everyone on Stackoverflow!
I have been working on this problem and have had no luck.  I want to import a csv file into my mysql database, but I keep getting error 1: "data too long for column 'upc' at row 1" and error 2: "Parameter '@sku' has already been defined".  Error 1 comes up once and error 2, i guess repeats until the loop ends. My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
//using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace cvsimporttrial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();

            fd.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
            fd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
            fd.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = fd.FileName;
        }

        private void btnSaveToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = "server=localhost;user id=*****;password=*****;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=*****";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into testimport values (@sku,@itemname,@itemdescription,@upc)";
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

               try
               {
                   con.Open();
                   cmd.Prepare(); 
                   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
                    {

                    dt.Columns.Add("sku");
                    dt.Columns.Add("ItemName");
                    dt.Columns.Add("ItemDescription");
                    dt.Columns.Add("upc");


                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {// Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        //DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        String line = sr.ReadLine();    //sr.ReadToEnd();
                        string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                        foreach (DataColumn cols in dt.Columns)
                        {   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["sku"]= columns[0];
                                 if (columns[0] == "sku") { continue; }//skip the heading as database already has heading, is there any other way to achieve this.
                            dr["ItemName"]= columns[1];
                            dr["ItemDescription"] = columns[2];
                            dr["upc"]= columns[3];
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            //Console.WriteLine(columns[3]);
                        }//foreach loop
                        //Console.WriteLine(line);
                        //Console.WriteLine(columns[0]);
                        //Console.WriteLine(columns[1]);
                        //Console.WriteLine(columns[2]);
                        //Console.WriteLine(columns[3]);
                        try
                        {

                            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                //cmd.Parameters["@sku"].Value = r["sku"];
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", r["sku"]);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname", r["ItemName"]);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemdescription", r["ItemDescription"]);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", r["upc"]);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }//mysql try block
                        catch (MySqlException mse) { MessageBox.Show(mse.Message); }//mysql catch

                    }//while loop

                }
            }//try block for file stream
             catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }//catch for file stream

        }//btnSaveToDatabase_click event

    }
}
```

My csv file sample is:
sku,ItemName,ItemDescription,upc
XY-1-12-ZX,Coke Zero cans 100 ml - pack of 12, "Get refreshing taste of coke with zero sugar",6111111113

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this an attempt to reinvent LOAD DATA IN FILE?

Comment: I did try "LOAD DATA INFILE test.csv INTO TABLE testimport FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 LINES (sku,ItemName,ItemDescription,upc)" but hit a dead end.  Am I writing this sql statement correctly to query against the csv file that looks like I have described above?

Comment: what was the so called dead end. Was tehre an error?

Comment: yes, there was an error that said "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test.csv INTO TABLE testimport FIELD' at line 1.  I tried looking for error in syntax, but could not spot any.?? so gave up on this route.

Comment: Filename should be in quotes. Why don't you update the answer and mention that you tried load data before switching to c# in that give the exact query that you used.

Comment: button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = "str";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            string query = String.Format("LOAD DATA INFILE {0} INTO TABLE testimport FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (sku,ItemName,ItemDescription,upc)",textBox1.Text);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();}

Comment: i had to shorten the code and have just pasted relevant code that I tried. I have no errors (the one I described in the comment above) in the code other than the syntax of load data statement.

Comment: @e4c5: Also, the reason I was using datatable (initial code I posted) is that I was thinking ahead about checking integrity of data that is being copied in mysql.  If I use load data, there is no way of checking, for eg., if an sku exist in database already.  Once the initial code works, I was planning to add on additional checks to data.  Good or bad idea, ??

Comment: Integrity checks need to happen at the database. iF you have proper indexes load data in file will take care of it. Didn't you try load data from the console?

Comment: I am trying to have integrity checks assuming if an end user was to import a csv file that needs to be saved in dbs, they won't have a clue re integrity of data and will only lead to further problems in future which will be hard to trace.  the only way they will be comfortable importing data is clicking button.  I could be overthinking this, if you have been in industry for long and if u think otherwise, please advise.

Comment: If you are importing dirty data, load data infile is going to throw errors and stop. Your code will do the same unless you set up a checkpoint for every row which is going to make the insert even really slow. There is no reason why a click of a button cannot be tied to a LOAD DATA

Comment: Agreed! :)) Thanks a lot for your time. I never thot of posting questions on stackoverflow as too many people with "reputation" do not entertain questions that THEY think is silly, but I appreciate your patience and help.  Keep sharing ur wisdom! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here... When you create your columns

```
    dt.Columns.Add("sku");
```

This creates a column of type string named "sku". If your MySQL table isn't only storing strings but other types, I'm guessing you'll get this or a very similar error.

Try adding types to your dt.column.add. This is the link to supported datatypes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for your response.  I tried your suggestion and unfortunately did not get far.  Have another error saying "sku does not belong to the table".  I checked my database for any spelling error but there is none. any other wild guesses :))

Comment: Sorry for the long delay... been oddly busy. Sadly I don't have anything off the top of my head. Good luck though!